# How to view all calls logs for a contact?

Tags: contacts, call-history

I am using **Galaxy S 3** phone with **Android 4.1.2**

Is there a way to view all call logs for a specific contact?

Answer (score 2):

View a contact (either from the **Contacts** app or by clicking them in the **Phone** app). Then press the menu hard-key, and **History** is the first item on the list.

Note: my Samsung Galaxy S III has been upgraded to Android 4.3, so I've no idea if the method is the same in Android 4.1.2, or if this is something Samsung has added since then. If anyone is still on 4.1.2, please check and comment!

Comment: Well, my 2c is that this doesn't work on my Android 4.2.2 device.

Answer (score 1):

I have Google voice, in addition to my cell carrier's assigned phone number, so this may not be true for everyone, but you can use Google Takeout to download all your data for any Google service you use. Just go to www.google.com/settings/takeout, and pick the services you want to review. Google will pack them all up in an archive which you can then download and search. A little painful if you do this on a regular basis, but a life-saver if you need to check something that is no longer on your phone, but is kept in your online history.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to filter the call log for a specific contact in 4.1.2 You would have to find an application on the Play store to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question to this elsewhere and was pointed to this thread, which did not really answer my question either. Posting my question, I thought that I may get some answers here, as it is, after many hours searching and trying various apps out, I have found a few apps that provide solutions myself, the best two of which I will list below.

I was looking for an app to show "call" & "sms" "history"/"logs" for an individual contact, so using these search terms I found many, the best stand alone one I found is called "My Log" from "Intangible Solutions" which is able to search and list all calls and sms for any given number or multiple numbers in a very clear and easy to read format. The drawbacks is that it is heavily add supported and takes a little while to specify all the contact's numbers, as you have to select them one at a time, having said this, the results are brilliant.

The other I found via an associated app call "Call log+" which I tried and initially dismissed as it only gave me call log similar to the one found in the standard "Phone" dialler, however I later went back to it's associated app "Contacts+", which includes "Call log+", "Messages+" and "Dialler+", and then also installed "Merge+", "Emoji for Conacts+" and the "Contacts+ Widget" to get the full collection, which can replace the standard "Phone", "Contacts" and "Messaging" functions with much better versions, that do far more. The "Contacts+", which includes "Call Log+" does everything I wanted, in that I can instantly see a call log for any contact. The fact that "Contacts+" does a whole lot more beyond this, is also fantastic, but it does exactly what I wanted, so job done.

I hope this may help others looking for the same missing (removed) feature, which because of how I use my phone, I would find hard to live without.

Answer (score 0):

[SMS backup +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en), copies your call logs to your GMail account which then groups them by contact