# how can I get the Call & SMS log for an individual contact?

Tags: contacts, call-history

I have recently upgraded to an Android 4.0.4 phone, used to have 2.3 and one of the features I used very often is missing.

In any contact I could look to see a list of calls & sms, including when I last called, received a call, had a missed call, or sent or received a text from that contact and from what number, i.e., Mobile, Mobile work, Home, Work, etc.

This was especially useful for checking when I last had contact with somebody, such as clients, allowing me to decide if I needed to call or send them a text.

This feature has obviously been removed, however is there any third party apps available that could either stand alone, or preferably integrate to allow me this much used & needed feature back.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to view all calls logs for a contact?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46886)

Comment: Just looked at the "possible duplicate" and to some degree it is, however I already recognise that in 4.x I can not by default, I used to be able in 2.x, so surely there are apps out there that can provide this feature, my question, which the other post did not really answer, is what are they, I have already spent hours searching for them, some go part way to providing the feature that has been removed, but I have not found one yet that gets close. Surely an app or two exist?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I may get some answers here, as it is, after many hours searching and trying various apps out, I have found a few apps that provide solutions myself, the best two of which I will list below.

I was looking for an app to show "call" & "sms" "history"/"logs", so using these search terms I found many, the best stand alone one I found is called "My Log" from "Intangible Solutions" which is able to search and list all calls and sms for any given number or multiple numbers in a very clear and easy to read format. The drawbacks is that it is heavily add supported and takes a little while to specify all the contact's numbers, as you have to select them one at a time, having said this, the results are brilliant.

The other I found via an associated app call "Call log+" which I tried and initially dismissed as it only gave me call log similar to the one found in the standard "Phone" dialler, however I later went back to it's associated app "Contacts+", which includes "Call log+", "Messages+" and "Dialler+", and then also installed "Merge+", "Emoji for Conacts+" and the "Contacts+ Widget" to get the full collection, which can replace the standard "Phone", "Contacts" and "Messaging" functions with much better versions, that do far more. The "Contacts+", which includes "Call Log+" does everything I wanted, in that I can instantly see a call log for any contact. The fact that "Contacts+" does a whole lot more beyond this is also fantastic, but it does exactly what I wanted, so job done.

I hope this may help others looking for the same missing (removed) feature, which because of how I use my phone, I would find hard to live without.